# how to select project element in project explorer (eclipse plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I'm writing an Eclipse command plugin and want to select the first project in the project explorer view.
note, that no editor is opened.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the active workbench page and find the view:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IViewPart viewPart = page.findView(id);
```

The id for the Projects View is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ProjectsView`

If the view is not open `viewPart` will be `null`.

Get the selection provider from the view site:

```
ISelectionProvider selProvider = viewPart.getSite().getSelectionProvider();
```

Set selection:

```
selProvider.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(project));
```

`project` is the `IProject` object for the project you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237056/how-to-select-project-element-in-project-explorer-eclipse-plugin?rq=1) is correct but the "Projects View" id worked for me is `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer` on Eclipse 4.6